# AirWatch Authentication Failure

Tags: ios, authentication, mdm, enterprise-distribution, airwatch

I am working on an iOS App which will be distributed within an enterprise using AirWatch as an MDM Tool.

I have integrated AirWatch iOS SDK in my app, but, I am getting a failure on authentication on both Device and Simulator. I use the same credentials which I used to enroll the device. The error screenshot is below:

[image: App Authentication Failure]

My Device is successfully enrolled with AirWatch, see the screenshot below:

[image: Enrollment Successful.]

Do I need to setup something in AirWatch Console in order for my app to get authenticated with AirWatch?

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this setting helped me from Airwatch console. Go to Groups and settings > All settings > Devices and Users > General > Enrollment > (Turn off the 'Require Registration Token') setting.

Comment: Hey! Could you please tell, how did you get AirWatch SDK? I've have troubles with it. here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53023149/2510002

Answer (score 0):

You have to create SDK Profile first using Airwatch Console and upload your app using that profile on Airwatch console.

From the AirWatch console, select Apps and Profiles > Profiles.
Click Add to create a new Profile.
Select Platform

and assign this profile to your app while uploading to airwatch console.

For more details refer to Airwatch Resources and iOS SDK Developer Guide

Comment: Hey! Could you please tell, how did you get AirWatch SDK? I've have troubles with it. here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53023149/2510002

Comment: @Alex below are the links
https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/5.9.3/airwatch-ios
https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/16.4.1/airwatch-android

You need to login.

Comment: and it's not free. Thank you @prathameshr!

Answer (score 0):

@Prathameshr Answer is correct.

Too enable SDK use in the application choose you app, select "edit", click "more" and choose "SDK". See screenshot for details

[image]