# How can I download Airwatch iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, mdm, airwatch

Maybe a bit stupid question, but how to download AirWatch iOS SDK?
I can't download AirWatch SDK. I am logged in (https://code.vmware.com, and https://resources.workspaceone.com/) but get an error

> "An error occurred retrieving resource with UID xxxxxxxxxxxx. You may
>   not have access to view this resource."

on resources.workspaceone.com.

Anybody who have did it already, could you please give an advice?

Comment: You should have an paid account for downloading an AIRWatch SDK.

Comment: good to hear. Review my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an paid account for downloading the Complete AIRWatch SDK kit which include the required SDK & their documentation.

Comment: you actually don't need to have a paid account. I've just registered and downloaded sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Open https://resources.workspaceone.com/ in safari browser to avoid errors. In chromes i am also getting some weird error. see attached screen shot.
[image]